# Sum each column value and other column values that contain this column value in groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
        'value': ['red','red and blue','yellow, red and blue','oak','oak wood'],
        'volume': [10, 3, 2, 15, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value'])
```

I want the sum of `volume` for each column value `value` and column values that contain this `value` grouped by `id` and `value`. Result expected:

```
id value                 sum
1  red                    15
1  red and blue           5
1  yellow, red and blue   2
2  oak                    20
2  oak wood               5
```

How do I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the entire string always a substring of the other? like `red and blue`, is as a whole part of `yellow, red and blue`, but is there a chance that there is also are `red and green` that has to be matched with `red` but not with `yellow, red and blue`?

Comment: @Finn there is a chance that eg `red and green` cannot be matched anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call it `sum` as the name is not very descriptive and there is also a `sum()` function. The function loops over each `id` and then over each row with the current `id`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
        'value': ['red','red and blue','yellow, red and blue','oak','oak wood'],
        'volume': [10, 3, 2, 15, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value','volume'])#.set_index('id')
df['volume_sum'] = 0 # add new column

for cur_id in df.id.unique(): #for each id
    for cur_index,cur_row in df[df.id == cur_id].iterrows() : # for each row in that id
        df.loc[cur_index,'volume_sum'] = sum(df[(df.id == cur_id) & (df.value.str.contains(cur_row['value']))].volume)

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I thought the same approach by loop but I have a data set with more than 1m rows. it takes really long. And I got an error `unbalanced parenthesis at position 1`

Comment: does it makes this error if you copy it in a new file? what python version do you have? this is 3.7. With that much data matching strings might not be the best way. can you classify the data earlier?

Comment: yes I use 3.7. This is already the final version i can use before the loop..

Comment: As mentioned, comparing strings will always be slow. So you propably should classify the date before you start the loop. But for that you have to show more of the acutal data. i recommend you to ask a new question for that

Comment: the data is the same as in the example. three columns and I need to group by `id` and `value`. it just has mamy more rows.